# Expanding string with multiple substrings

Tags: string, bash

I need to extract data from a string which contains several substrings.

Example:

```
@string1 = "string 1"
@string2 = "string 2"
@string3 = "string 3" @string1 @string2
```

I need to expand string3. The result would be:

"string3 string2 string1"

How can I expand the list using Bash?

---

Actually I need to read a part of a existing gitolite config file so the formatting is correct. The string always starts with '@'. A string can contain a substring.

This is how the format looks like:

```
@string1 = hello
@string2 = everyone 
@resultstring = @string1 @string2 this is a string
```

Now I want to expand @resultstring. The result would be: "hello everyone this is a string"

Comment: Can you explain the logic: `"string 3" @string1 @string2` -> `"string3 string2 string1"`

Comment: This syntax doesn't seem like `bash` to me.

Comment: are you sure you're not thinking of `string1="string 1" ; .... string3="string3 " $string1 " " $string2`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is

```
string1='string 1'
string2='string 2'
string3="string 3 $string1 $string2"
```

Single quotes are for strong quoting, no expansion of variables, while on the other hand you can expand variables within double quotes.

Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: @ErikB, take note of the syntax in this answer: no leading `@`, no spaces around the `=`, use `$` to "dereference" a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If the " = " is hardcoded elsewhere, you can use this awk helper with any posix shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
print_var(){
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=" = "}
    {   if ($1=="'$1'"){
            len=split($2,words," ")
            for(i=0;i<=len;i++){
                if (match(words[i],"@")) printf strings[words[i]]
                else printf words[i]
                printf (i==len)?"\n":" "
            }
        } else strings[$1]=$2
    }' $2
}

print_var @resultstring input
```

or if bash-4.0isms are ok,you could read that strings to an associative array directly

```
#!/bin/bash
print_var(){
    declare -A STRINGS
    while read FIRST EQUAL STRING || [ "$FIRST" ]; do
        case $FIRST in
        @*)STRINGS["${FIRST#@}"]="$STRING";;
        esac
    done < "$2"
    for x in ${STRINGS[${1#@}]};  do
        case $x in
        @*)printf "%s " ${STRINGS[${x#@}]};;
        *)printf "%s " "$x";;
        esac
    done
    echo
}

print_var @resultstring input
```

Comment: Note: for the bash version I set it up so you can leave off the @ prefix